# Residue fields of $\mathbb Z[X_1,...,X_n]$ are always finite ?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $\mathfrak m$ be a maximal ideal of $\mathbb Z[X_1,...,X_n]$;

then is it necessarily true that $\mathbb Z[X_1,...,X_n]/\mathfrak m$ is finite ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it follows from [Zariski's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski%27s_lemma).

Comment: could you please care to elaborate ?